# facebook android sdk authentication is asynchronous. How to deal with it?

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating FB sign-on in my app. I am having problems with the asynchronous nature of the process. If I am not logged into FB then I am shown a dialog to enter my passwd but when I am already logged the whole process becomes asynchronous and my original activity runs through. This is creating problems for me because my logic is dependent on the result of the FB authentication. I am sure others must have run into it. How do I deal with this?

EDIT:

In other words my problem is that the function I am calling is returning immediately. It does its thing by spawning a thread and returns the results through a callback I implement. In this scenario, I want to wait for that function to return (or the callback to be called) and only continue processing afterwards.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks
- P

Comment: Are you using the facebook sdk?  Possibly paste some code of where you are running into problems, I am sure they have added some sort of callback to hook into.

Answer (score 2):

Well, pretty much everything that has you interacting with the web will be asynchronous, so be aware of that in the design of your application. One of the most accepted ways of dealing with this sort of logic in Android is to create AsyncTasks. You would spin up an authentication request AsyncTask and show a progress dialog while it is performing the operation. When it comes back you hide the progress dialog and continue with your application logic.

Comment: That is not quite my problem here. Its in fact the opposite. Please see the edit I made to the question above. The calling function is spawning a thread and returning immediately. I want to wait for the thread functionality to be complete before doing my thing.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused about what your problem is then, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

here is another example code for authentication, you can use RequestListener to get the callback etc.

https://github.com/wareninja/generic-oauth2-login-for-android

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad idea to freeze the main thread until an async operation completes. There's a reason why it's async. Much better to display a modal progress window, let the control return to the OS and resume work upon completion. This way, you're getting the best of both worlds - the user cannot do anything until the authentication is over, and you don't freeze the phone.